# Java Selenium Htmlunit Driver Javascript error

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

Is there any other option to disable javascript in HtmlUnit. While navigating HtmlUnit it not processing further it going in infinite loop, so i am trying to disable javascript using following code

webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false)

but its not working.

Comment: This is a Question&Answer site, not Try&Guess- please improve your Q

Comment: give more information or your question will be deleted. like Franz said cannot guess

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs at [htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/) the correct form should be:

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false)
```